# C# using points' offset method in foreach loop to modify array of points

Tags: c#, foreach, point

I am having trouble understanding how points' offset method works within a foreach loop to modify an existing array of points. I am able to do it by manually indexing each array entity, but I strongly suspect that is not how it should be done.

*Edit To be clear. What is the best way to store my offset points in MyPoints array?

See code below. I used http://rextester.com/ online C# compiler to test the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Drawing;
namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        static int ii = 0;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Point[] MyPoints = 
            {
                new Point(0,0),
                new Point(10,10),
                new Point(20,0)
            };

            foreach(Point p in MyPoints)
            {
                p.Offset(5,2); //this works but does not store the new points                 
            }                  //in MyPoints array when the foreach loop 
                               //exits, which is what I want.

        Console.WriteLine("p1x = {0} \t p1y = {1}", MyPoints[0].X, MyPoints[0].Y);
        Console.WriteLine("p2x = {0} \t p2y = {1}", MyPoints[1].X, MyPoints[1].Y);
        Console.WriteLine("p3x = {0} \t p3y = {1} \n", MyPoints[2].X, MyPoints[2].Y);

        foreach(Point p in MyPoints)
        {
            MyPoints[ii].Offset(5,2);
            ii++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("p1x = {0} \t p1y = {1}", MyPoints[0].X, MyPoints[0].Y);
        Console.WriteLine("p2x = {0} \t p2y = {1}", MyPoints[1].X, MyPoints[1].Y);
        Console.WriteLine("p3x = {0} \t p3y = {1}", MyPoints[2].X, MyPoints[2].Y);
        }
    }
}
//This yields the following
/*
p1x = 0      p1y = 0
p2x = 10     p2y = 10
p3x = 20     p3y = 0 

p1x = 5      p1y = 2
p2x = 15     p2y = 12
p3x = 25     p3y = 2*/
```

Comment: What's your question? You've stated a few things but you've never actually asked anything.

Comment: Ok. I edited my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`System.Drawing.Point` is a structure - a value type. The `foreach` loop copies the `Point` value out of the collection into the `p` variable. You then modify the `p` variable by calling `Offset`, but that doesn't change the collection at all, because it's only the *copy* that's modified.

In your second loop, you're modifying the value in the array directly - which is why you're seeing the difference.

A more idiomatic way of doing that would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyPoints.Length; i++)
{
    MyPoints[i].Offset(5, 2);
}
```

It's worth noting that `Point` is relatively unusual as it's a *mutable* value type - the `Offset` method really changes the value. Most value types (e.g. `DateTime`) are immutable - methods like `AddDays` don't modify the value they're called on; instead they return a *new* value. So to do something similar with an array of dates, you'd need code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dates.Length; i++)
{
    dates[i] = dates[i].AddDays(10);
}
```

Or you could use LINQ to create a new array:

```
DateTime[] newDates = dates.Select(date => date.AddDays(10)).ToArray();
```

You couldn't write it exactly like that for `Point` because of the way `Offset` returns `void`. You'd need something like:

```
Point[] newPoints = points.Select(point => { point.Offset(5,2); return point; })
                          .ToArray();
```

Comment: I am not OP, but can you elaborate why the first foreach-loop doesn't change the collection, since it modifies the variable? You wrote it pretty clearly, but I still don't fully understand

Comment: Ok. This was very helpful, and answered my question. Thank you!

Comment: @thesystem I think the keyword is _copy_. The way I understood it is that p simply is a copy and does not effect what it was copied from. Say you have a variable A, then make a copy of it and call it B. Changing B will not change A. But that is just how I understood it and I am very new to C#, so I would definitely verify it.

Comment: @Ndnes Your explanation is reasonable. Thanks!

Comment: @thesystem: I've added half a sentence to help clarify. (And yes, it is indeed because it's a copy.)